# Can a piezo disc be connected directly to a op amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, esp32

I'm trying to use a piezo disc as a sensor do detect slight vibrations, I see the signal on an oscilloscope, it needs to be amplified. But I can't manage to amplife it.

For this, I wanted to use a simple inverting op amp circuit :
[image]

I also tried by replacing the power supply by two 9V batteries and using the the middle as a virual ground. without much more sucess.

1. Is there something I'm missing ?
2. Do I need to add something ?
3. Will the version exclusively powered by the esp32 work ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: why don't you have a charge amplifier before your main amplifier? Piezo gives current which is proportional to rate of change of force applied to it. Moreover, adding that will also solve high source impedance problem of piezo.

Comment: Thank you very much, I learned a lot, thanks to your comment. 
I did so, and got better results but still need further testing !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something I'm missing?

Yes. The piezo is a very high-impedance source. Your R2 effectively does nothing, and your R1 value is way too low to create any voltage gain.

You can think of a piezo sensor as essentially a capacitor. The piezoelectric effect causes a small amount of charge to move into or out of this capacitor.

> Do I need to add something?

Delete R2 and make R1 much larger, on the order of megohms.

> Will the version exclusively powered by the esp32 work?

You need to define "work", but the answer is probably not well. It would be better to bias the inputs to half the supply voltage for single-supply operation.

Also, the output of the LM324 is not rail-to-rail. It can pull to ground, but at only up to 50 µA of current.

Answer (score 1):

You may have destroyed the ESP32 when you used two batteries because the op-amp will then be capable of delivering significantly more that 3.3 volts into your IO pin. Always use a series current limiting resistor when doing things like this - wire it in series with the IO line, something like 10 kohms.

Regarding the amplifier and the piezo disc, you need to have a high impedance input to get decent voltage levels from the piezo. Your circuit appears to have an input impedance of 1.21 kohms and this is really quite low - you should be considering a resistor in the mega ohms region for this. So R1 and R2 at 1 Mohms stands a better chance to work but don't forget the series current limiter for the IO pin.

You can use a single supply of at least 5 volts for the op-amp. 3.3 volts will be too small to detect any digital change on the output of the LM324 most likely. Running from a single supply will mean that you only amplify half the signal produced by the piezo disc but, as you are using it to detect vibration it will probably work. If you are using it to measure vibration then you will need a different arrangement that's a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You did a wrong bias circuit. Rg and Rf have to be choosen for gain factor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4amVq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Non-Inverting, high input impedance circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWju0k.png)</sup>

Comment: His circuit is inverting, your's is noninverting.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Changed to inverting

Comment: Then your input impedance is probably too low.

Comment: @ScottSeidman That's why I started with non-inverting setup. But why did you post your answer "Configure your amplifier as a NONINVERTING" and you commented my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Configure your amplifier as a NONINVERTING amplifier, which has a much higher input impedance.